# Display only selected fields from nested MongoDB collection

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a MongoDB collection as follows:

```
[{'_id': ObjectId('60d0a244102671b912874755'),
  'entities': [{'uen': 'ABC',
    'name': 'COMPANY NAME',
    'persons': [{'personId': '12345',
                 'personNationality': 'CITIZEN',
                 'personName': 'TJY'},
                {'personId': '6789',
                 'personNationality': 'CITIZEN',
                 'personName': 'ABC'}]}]}]
```

I am using PyMongo to retrieve information where `personId = 6789` but not 12345. The ideal output should look like:

```
[{'_id': ObjectId('60d0a244102671b912874755'),
  'entities': [{'uen': 'ABC',
    'name': 'COMPANY NAME',
    'persons': [{'personId': '6789',
                 'personNationality': 'CITIZEN',
                 'personName': 'ABC'}]}]}]
```

However, whenever I run my code, the output still includes `personId = 12345` although I explicitly indicated the filtering condition for only `personId = 6789`:

```
output = []
result = db.collection.find({'entities.uen': 'ABC',
                                  'entities.persons.personId': '6789'},
               {'entities.uen':1,
                'entities.name':1,
                'entities.persons.personId': 1,
                'entities.persons.personName': 1,
                'entities.persons.personNationality': 1})

for i in result:
    output.append(i)
```

And the output is as follows:

```
[{'_id': ObjectId('60d0a244102671b912874755'),
  'entities': [{'uen': 'ABC',
    'name': 'COMPANY NAME',
    'persons': [{'personId': '12345',
      'personNationality': 'CITIZEN',
      'personName': 'TJY'},
     {'personId': '6789',
      'personNationality': 'CITIZEN',
      'personName': 'ABC'}]}]}]
```

I have also tried using `$elemMatch` but the output did not change:

```
db.collection.find({'entities.uen': 'ABC',
                          'entities.persons': {
                              '$elemMatch': {'personId': '6789'}}},
                         {'entities.uen':1,
                          'entities.name':1,
                          'entities.persons.personId.$': 1,
                          'entities.persons.personName': 1,
                          'entities.persons.personNationality': 1})
```

Will greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve it like this using an aggregation pipeline instead,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $unwind: '$entities' },
    {
      $match: {
        $expr:{
          $eq: ['$entities.uen', 'ABC']
        }
      }
    },

    {
      $project: {
            'persons': {
                $filter: {
                  input: "$entities.persons",
                  as: "someObj",
                  cond: { $eq: [ '$$someObj.personId', '6789' ] }
                }
            },
            'entities.uen' : 1,
            'entities.name' : 1
        }
    },
    {
      $group:{
        _id : '$_id',
        entities: {$push: {
            uen : '$entities.uen',
            name : '$entities.name',
            persons : '$persons'
        }
        }
      }
    }  
])
```